# how can I access nested or sub array in Json using Retrofit in Kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, json, kotlin, retrofit2

This is my Json data and I want to access Item array in sections. I've cutted my json because it is too long the way I'm getting this array I get arrayOutOfBound Error.

```
{
   "status":"true",
    "sections":[
      {
         "type":"items",
         "label":"Just Arrived ",
         "items":[
            {
               "id":16676,
               "item_title":"Beauty Clinic Antibacterial Hand Sanitizer Non Sticky & Moisturizer, 225ML",
               "currency":"AED",
               "mainprice":15,
               "price":15,
               "deal_enabled":"no",
               "market_price":35,
               "discount_percentage":57,
               "valid_till":"",
               "quantity":46,
               "cod":"yes",
               "liked":"no",
               "grade":"Brand New",
               "grade_color":"#00af41",
               "report":"no",
               "shipping_time":"Three business days",
               "image":"https:\/\/cartlow.com\/media\/items\/thumb350\/1584281034_6.jpeg"
            },
            {
               "id":2561,
               "item_title":"Samsung Galaxy M10 Dual SIM - 16GB, 2GB RAM, 4G LTE, Charcoal Black - UAE Version",
               "currency":"AED",
               "mainprice":329,
               "price":329,
               "deal_enabled":"no",
               "market_price":449,
               "discount_percentage":27,
               "valid_till":"",
               "quantity":1,
               "cod":"yes",
               "liked":"no",
               "grade":"Pre-owned",
               "grade_color":"#ff671b",
               "report":"no",
               "shipping_time":"Three business days",
               "image":"https:\/\/cartlow.com\/media\/items\/thumb350\/1572942674_6.jpg"
            },
            {
               "id":15944,
               "item_title":"OnePlus 7 Pro 256GB 8GB RAM 4G LTE - Almond",
               "currency":"AED",
               "mainprice":1999,
               "price":1999,
               "deal_enabled":"no",
               "market_price":2999,
               "discount_percentage":33,
               "valid_till":"",
               "quantity":1,
               "cod":"yes",
               "liked":"no",
               "grade":"Brand New",
               "grade_color":"#00af41",
               "report":"no",
               "shipping_time":"Three business days",
               "image":"https:\/\/cartlow.com\/media\/items\/thumb350\/195d0fc3aa4198faebc46654eed1cc83.jpg"
            },
            {
               "id":9806,
               "item_title":"OnePlus 7T Pro - 256GB, 8GB RAM, 4G LTE - Haze Blue",
               "currency":"AED",
               "mainprice":1990,
               "price":1990,
               "deal_enabled":"no",
               "market_price":2799,
               "discount_percentage":29,
               "valid_till":"",
               "quantity":9,
               "cod":"yes",
               "liked":"no",
               "grade":"Pre-owned",
               "grade_color":"#ff671b",
               "report":"no",
               "shipping_time":"Three business days",
               "image":"https:\/\/cartlow.com\/media\/items\/thumb350\/f76fa006c5574ac25d6a257b7558dce3.jpg"
            },
```

I'm using Kotlin language and Retrofit Api to access this data but unable to get this array My Model classes are these

```
data class HomeResponseModel(
    val banner: List<Banner>? = null,
    val category: List<Category>? = null,
    val daily_deals: DailyDeals? = null,
    val home_message: String? = null,
    val home_message_color: String? = null,
    val sections: List<Section>? = null,
    val status: String? = null
)
data class Section(
    val category: String? = null,
    val items: List<Item>? = null,
    val label: String? = null,
    val type: String? = null
)
data class Item(
    val category: String? = null,
    val cod: String? = null,
    val currency: String? = null,
    val deal_enabled: String? = null,
    val discount_percentage: Int? = null,
    val grade: String? = null,
    val grade_color: String? = null,
    val id: Int? = null,
    val image: String? = null,
    val image_color: String? = null,
    val item_title: String? = null,
    val liked: String? = null,
    val mainprice: Int? = null,
    val market_price: Int? = null,
    val name: String? = null,
    val price: Int? = null,
    val product_id: String? = null,
    val quantity: Int? = null,
    val report: String? = null,
    val section_category: String? = null,
    val section_id: String? = null,
    val section_label: String? = null,
    val section_type: String? = null,
    val shipping_time: String? = null,
    val title_color: String? = null,
    val valid_till: String? = null
)
```

This is my simple Retrofit code in get Response

```
val retrofitBuilder = Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("https://stg.cartlow.com/")
            .build()
        val jsonApi = retrofitBuilder.create(ApiDataParsing::class.java)

        jsonApi.getHome(
            null,
            "android",
            18,
            "UAE",
            "AED",
            "Arabic"

        ).enqueue(object : Callback<HomeResponseModel>
        {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<HomeResponseModel>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("Error","Section List Error! $t")
            }
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<HomeResponseModel>, response: Response<HomeResponseModel>) {
                sectionAdapter = SectionAdapter(response.body()?.Section as List<Section>)
                sectionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                section_list.adapter = sectionAdapter
                }

        })
    }
```

In my RecyclerView adapter class where I'm getting IndexOutOfBound error because I don't know how to get items

```
var categoryList = categoryList[position].items?.get(position)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code giving IndexoutofBound Exception because you are using an Index(position) to access an element from "List</Item/>"  which is larger than the size of the "List</Item/>".So You need to check first whether the index(position) is less than the size of the array/list.

```
if(position< categoryList[position].items?.size)
var categoryList = categoryList[position].items?.get(position)
```

Or
if u want the item list u can just get the item list from response like below

```
var itemList= categoryList[position].items
```

then you can use the itemList as u want